# XGBoost warning: running on cuda while input data is on cpu

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I tried to train a XGBoost model using GPU acceleration.
When training my model using gridsearch, I get the following warning:

> UserWarning: [17:29:04] WARNING:
> /workspace/src/common/error_msg.cc:58: Falling back to prediction
> using DMatrix due to mismatched devices. This might lead to higher
> memory usage and slower performance. XGBoost is running on: cuda:0,
> while the input data is on: cpu. Potential solutions:
>
> - Use a data structure that matches the device ordinal in the booster.
> - Set the device for booster before call to inplace_predict.

Although some potential solutions are given, I'm not sure how to interpret them and what to do with this information.
Surprisingly, it only appears when using GridSearchCV.
In my minimal example below, I do not get the warning if I use `reg` directly instead of `gs`.

My `X` and `y` variables come from hdf5 files that I read using pandas.
Can anybody give me a hint on how I might improve my code to not raise the warning?

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    X = np.random.randn(100,2)
    y = np.random.randn(100)

    reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(device="cuda", tree_method="hist", max_depth=10, n_estimators=100)
    param_grid = {"gamma": [0.3]}

    gs = GridSearchCV(reg, param_grid, cv=5)
    gs.fit(X,y)     # warning
    # reg.fit(X,y)  # no warning
```

packages:

```
xgboost==2.0.1 
scikit-learn==1.3.2
```

Comment: The warning appears to be related to the use of `parallel` in sklearn to run the grid search (specifically https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/093e0cf14aff026cca6097e8c42f83b735d26358/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L845). Not sure how to avoid this other than roll your own search that doesn't use parallel

Comment: I have the same issue when training XGBoost model using CUDA. Does anyone know, if it is related to not using RAPIDS Memory Manager?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been raised on the XGBoost GitHub repo. check [#9791](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/9791) and [#9594](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/9594).

The solution proposed is to use cupy or cudf as input types to match the device=cuda.

An example with cupy below:

```
xgb = XGBRegressor(device="cuda")
xgb.fit(cupy.array(X), y)
```